# Use send() on a related collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have some lists, which are almost equal, just they are calling a different method (a scope method on a related model). So I thought I could use ruby's send method to call that method. But it fails with the error:

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3)

My (simplified) classes are:

```
class Zone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customers
  has_many :orders, through: :customers
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  scope :open, -> { where(status: 'open') }
end
```

So, if I call `@zone.orders.open`, I get all orders with the expected status.

But if I do `@zone.orders.send(:open)` it fails with the error mentioned above.

The idea is the use `.send()` for a partial, and just passing a symbol to retrieve other scopes on `@zone.orders`.

**On the rails console:**

> `2.5.1 :002 > zone = Zone.last => #<Zone id: ...> | > zone.orders.send(:open) | Creating scope :open. Overwriting existing
>   method Order.open. | Creating scope :route. Overwriting existing
>   method Order.route. | Traceback (most recent call last): | 3: from
>   (irb):3 2: from (irb):3:in open' 1: from (irb):3:in initialize' 
>   ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3))`

Comment: I've tested the `send` with your use case. It works for me! Are you sure that the error is caused by `send`? Posting the full error stacktrace would help

Comment: On the rails console: 2.5.1 :002 > zone = Zone.last
 => #<Zone id: ...>  | > zone.orders.send(:open) |
Creating scope :open. Overwriting existing method Order.open. |
Creating scope :route. Overwriting existing method Order.route. | 
Traceback (most recent call last): |
        3: from (irb):3
        2: from (irb):3:in `open'
        1: from (irb):3:in `initialize'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3))

Comment: Nevermind I've missed the `through: :customers`. My bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the name collides with `Kernel#open` which is used to open IO streams.

```
irb(main):001:0> z = Zone.create
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Zone Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "zones" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2018-10-19 16:29:40.018339"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-19 16:29:40.018339"]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Zone id: 10, created_at: "2018-10-19 16:29:40", updated_at: "2018-10-19 16:29:40">
irb(main):002:0> z.orders.send(:open)
Creating scope :open. Overwriting existing method Order.open.
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3)
    from (irb):2:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `open'
    from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0> z.orders.method(:open)
=> #<Method: Order::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy(Kernel)#open>
irb(main):004:0> z.orders.method(:open).call
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3)
    from (irb):4:in `initialize'
    from (irb):4:in `open'
    from (irb):4:in `call'
    from (irb):4
irb(main):005:0> z.orders
  Order Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "orders"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" WHERE "customers"."zone_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["zone_id", 10], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):006:0> z.orders.open
  Order Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "orders"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" WHERE "customers"."zone_id" = $1 AND "orders"."status" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["zone_id", 10], ["status", "open"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

As you can see the call goes to `Kernel#open` first and then goes to the method defined by the scope after  the collection is loaded. I'm guessing this is due to `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` doing some sort of lazy proxing to the association target class. Since the `CollectionProxy` already has an `open` method (Kernel#open) it uses it instead.

A simple solution here instead of dynamic calling would be to use a scope that takes an argument:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  scope :with_status, ->(status){ where(status: status.to_s) }
end
```

Or even better use [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) which is smart enough to properly work with the collection proxy.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  # you need to change the DB column to an integer type
  enum status: [:open, :closed]
end
```

Comment: Otherwise I don't really think there is a problem with clobbering `Kernel#open` in your class. Its not like you a re going to be calling `self.class.open` to open an IO pipe from inside a model. And you can open streams via super, Open3 or File anyways if needed.

Comment: Thank you max. I just change the scope name to check it and it works. I think I will use the simple solution.